# app x1 cannot access app x2 data

Tags: google-app-engine

I copied some namespace data from x1 to x2 using remote api and lowlevel datastore api.

I am accessing the x2 app, to get the following error for some data

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: app x1 cannot access app x2's data
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$CumulativeAggregateFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:145)
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in this post: [Migration to HRD - How to convert string-encoded keys to new application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760205/migration-to-hrd-how-to-convert-string-encoded-keys-to-new-application) all entity keys contain a reference to the app-id. If you use keys encoded as String, that reference won't be updated when copying data to a new application. But you can do it by yourself.

Just run a query in the new environment to update every single key to point to the new app-id. 
In this example i suppose that every entity implements this interface:

```
Interface Entity{
    public Key getKey();
    public void setKey(Key key); 
}
```

now i can use a method like this:

```
//... 

List<Entity> entities = //... your query

for (Entity entity : entities){
    entity.setKey(generateNewKey(entity.getKey());
}

//...

//Method written by Nikolay Ivanov in the other post, that recursive generate a new key respecting to parents

private Key generateNewKey(Key key) {  
    Key parentKey = key.getParent();
    if(parentKey == null){
        return KeyFactory.createKey(key.getKind(), key.getId());  
    }else{          
        Key newParentKey = generateKey(parentKey);         
        return KeyFactory.createKey(newParentKey, key.getKind(), key.getId());  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix up the keys so they have the right app ID in them.

Here's a bit of Python I use:

```
  key = db.Key(k)
  if key.app() == appname:
    return db.get(key)
  logging.info("Fixing up key from old app %s (%s=%s)" % ( key.app() , key_attr , k ))
  fixed_key = db.Key.from_path(*key.to_path())
```